# Ingresar 10 numeros unicamente pares

Tags: javascript

Me gustaria saber cual es el error que hace que el bucle no termine al ingresar un numero que no sea par. La consigna es "Realizar un programa que solo me permita ingresar numeros pares en un vector de 10 posiciones".

```
i=0;
var number = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  if (number%2==0) {
    var ingreso=prompt('Ingresa 10 numeros pares');
  }else{
    alert('Valor incorrecto. Intente nuevamente');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo has planteado de forma errónea. Tal y como lo tienes, haciendo un `for` vas a recorrer hasta 10 pero tu acumulador (`i`) va aumentar independientemente del valor que introduzcas por lo que, en el mejor de los casos, tendrías 10 números en tu array si todos fueran pares. Además, ahora mismo no los estás almacenando en ningún array.

Te dejo este ejemplo. Utilizando `while` se comprueba si su longitud es menor de 10. Si lo es te pide el número y se introduce en el array (con `push`) sólo en el caso en el que el valor introducido sea par. Si no lo es muestra un error. Si tienes cualquier duda no dudes en preguntar :)

```js
let numbers = [];
while(numbers.length<10){
  let ingreso = prompt('Ingresa un número par');
  if(ingreso){
    if(ingreso%2===0 && ingreso.trim() !== ""){
      numbers.push(ingreso);
    }
    else{
      alert('Valor incorrecto. Intente nuevamente');
    }
  }
}

console.log(numbers);
```

Comment: Kiko le faltan controles al código. Por ejemplo me acepta que le de a enter 10 veces y llena el array con elementos vacíos...

Comment: Tienes razón. He añadido un par de controles más (si el usuario pulsa "Cancelar" sigue pidiendo datos y el que comentas de elementos vacíos). Gracias!